# Ошибка: ОРА-01652: Невозможно увеличить временный сегмент до 8192 в разделе USERS

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldeveloper

Пытаюсь создать индекс. Но после долгих "раздумий" вылетает ошибка.
Воспользовавшись [советом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25350703/ora-01652-unable-to-extend-temp-segment-by-128-in-tablespace-system-how-to-ext) я создал для этого раздела еще один файл:

```
alter tablespace users add datafile E:\ORACLE\ORACLE10\DATABASE\new_segment_26062021_2.dbf'
    size 10m autoextend on maxsize unlimited;
```

Но по прежнему вылетает ошибка при создании индекса:

> Error encountered:
> ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 8192 in tablespace USERS
> The following SQL statement failed:
> CREATE INDEX MARKET.LINE_FLOWS_INDEXl ON MARKET.LINE_FLOWS (DD_MM_YYYY ASC)

Версия:

> Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production

Comment: А места на диске E много свободного ?

Comment: @Mike Оформите как ответ пожалуйста

Answer (score 5):

Первым делом проверьте, есть ли ещё свободное место на диске:

```
C:\> dir e:|find "bytes free"
              10 Dir(s)  99.138.351.104 bytes free
```

или более подробно как Администратор:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> fsutil volume diskfree е:
Total free bytes        :  99.138.351.104 ( 92,3 GB)
Total bytes             : 137.438.949.376 (128,0 GB)
Total quota free bytes  :  99.138.351.104 ( 92,3 GB)
```

При оценке учтите, что каждый файл данных может достичь макс. размера 32G.

---

Кроме того, если команда перенесена копи-пастой, то:

```
alter tablespace users add datafile E:\ORACLE\ORACLE10\DATABASE\new_segment_26062021_2.dbf' 
                                ----^
    size 10m autoextend on maxsize unlimited;
```

нет открывающей кавычки. Новый файл не создался.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но не было места на диске

Comment: @gregor Может быть, но команда которую вы предложили в вопросе никогда не была выполнена. Об отсутствии места на диске вас спросили в комментарии. Как надо было понять отсутствие ответа на него?

Comment: Согласен по поводу кавычки(как то потерялась ) , но ошибка была бы другая

Comment: Дико извиняюсь за несвоевременный ответ

Comment: @gregor Хорошо, я дополню ответ с учётом - "места не было". Вам уже конечно не поможет, но кому-нибудь, кто из поиска найдёт эту тему, возможно ещё поможет.

Comment: Дополнил, если так пойдёт, то вы можете удалить комментарии кроме первого.